# Executing a jQuery effect on demand. Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, client-side, jquery-events

I was looking the [Highlight](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Highlight) effect of jQuery's. That effect is really the one I would like to add in my web page.

By looking at the the source code, I noticed that the effect will be reproduced on user's click of the `div`.

```
$("div").click(function () {
      $(this).effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
});
```

In my web page I have an ImageButton

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnFavorite" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Favorite.png"/>
```

I would love to perform the highlight effect to the `div`, when the user clicks on the image button. Is it possible?

**UPDATE**: If it is possible, could I use something like `"OnClientClick="` of the ImageButton, since the imagebutton controls are added dynamically to the web page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply bind a [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) handler to your image button, like so:

```
$("#btnFavorite").click(function() {
    // selector for element to highlight
    $("#theDiv").effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
});
```

Update: If the control is dynamically added/replaced, you can use [`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to ensure that the event handler remains attached:

```
$("#btnFavorite").live("click", function() {
    // selector for element to highlight
    $("#theDiv").effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
});
```

Comment: some additional notes: asp.net changes the ids to make them unique (unless you set ClientIdMode to static), he'll propably need <%= btnFavorite.ClientID %>. I don't think live is required, he probably mean dynamicly server side (unless he use an asp:updatepanel)